# add Array Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I mean how can I get an array in Firestore?
[image]

For example, when I have a simple field I enter it with `[(ngModel)] ="proyecto.titulo"` but in this case, how do I enter the data in an array?

Comment: I am interested to know aswell

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save an array you can write `db.doc("documentName.etiquetas").set(["tag1", "tag2", "tag2"])`

this will end up as the structure you want.

However, it's better to save it as a map with index `0,1,2,...`. Because in that case you can directly reference and update the element. Eg. `db.doc("documentName.etiquetas.0").set("new tag1")`