# add / update array Firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm working with Firestore. The following code updates the matrix with a single element, that is, each time a user executes that function, said field is updated:

```
updateFavoritos(key) {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.afs.doc('eventos/' + key).update({
      favoritos: [ user.uid ],
    });
  }
```

This looks like this:
[image]

But how can I do to add instead of updating that matrix, is to say something like this:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47947533/9006622 duplicacted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update an "array of objects" with Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757614/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-with-firestore)

Answer (score 0):

Firestore have methods to handle arrays. Link to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)

```
var washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
    regions: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("greater_virginia")
});

// Atomically remove a region from the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
    regions: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove("east_coast")
});
```